# Question on how the Frameworx do the Encoding.Convert method

Tags: .net, string, encoding, arrays

I have lately been trying to read about how everything with strings and encodings work.

My question is this, the method:

```
public static byte[] Convert(
Encoding srcEncoding,
Encoding dstEncoding,
byte[] bytes
)
```

What is actually going on behind the scenes, is it using a StringBuilder to check each char and then replacing them according to the specified Encoding or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect it to be *effectively*:

```
string text = srcEncoding.GetString(bytes);
return destEncoding.GetBytes(text);
```

Now it may do it in a more memory-efficient way than that - but effectively it needs to decode the original binary data and encode it again as binary data in the other encoding.

Note that performing encoding on a character-by-character basis doesn't always work - for example, one UTF-8 byte sequence may decode to a single Unicode code point represented as a surrogate pair of UTF-16 code units (`char` values). Using an `Encoder` and Decoder`pair would allow "chunks" of data to be encoded/decoded at a time, removing the need for the whole text data to be in memory at one time... possibly writing to a`MemoryStream` or something similar to store the encoded data.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that was what id thought it did, thanx for taking the time to post